# Typescript get property always returns undefined in browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app

I have a typescript class that is defined as follows:

```
import { Security } from 'models/Security'

export type TradeType =
  | 'Buy'
  | 'Reinvest'
  | 'Sell'
  | 'Dividend'
  | 'Stock Split'
  | 'Starting Value'
  | null

type PositiveTradeType =
  | 'Buy'
  | 'Reinvest'
  | 'Dividend'
  | 'Stock Split'
  | 'Starting Value'

export interface ITrade {
  id?: number
  accountId: number
  settledOn: string
  tradeType: TradeType
  shares: number
  security?: Security
  priceCents: number
  basis?: number
  gain?: number
  securityId: number
}

export class Trade implements ITrade {
  id?: number
  accountId: number
  settledOn: string
  tradeType: TradeType
  shares: number
  security?: Security
  priceCents: number
  basis?: number
  gain?: number
  securityId: number

  constructor(
    accountId: number,
    settledOn: string,
    tradeType: TradeType,
    shares: number,
    priceCents: number,
    securityId: number,
    id?: number,
    security?: Security,
    basis?: number,
    gain?: number
  ) {
    this.id = id
    this.accountId = accountId
    this.settledOn = settledOn
    this.tradeType = tradeType
    this.shares = shares
    this.security = security
    this.priceCents = priceCents
    this.basis = basis
    this.gain = gain
    this.securityId = securityId
  }

  get holdingImpact(): number {
    if (!this.tradeType) {
      return 0
    }
    return this.isOfPositiveType(this.tradeType) ? this.shares : -this.shares
  }

  get settledOnDate(): Date {
    return new Date(this.settledOn)
  }

  isOfPositiveType(tradeType: string): tradeType is PositiveTradeType {
    return [
      'Buy',
      'Reinvest',
      'Dividend',
      'Stock Split',
      'Starting Value',
    ].includes(tradeType)
  }
}
```

In the browser (tried in both Chrome and Firefox), I am always getting "undefined" (with both `console.log` or in the debugger) when I try to access either of the get properties (via, e.g., `trade.holdingImpact`).

I have a jest test for this file and that property works as expected there.

Here is my tsconfig:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

The project was created with `create-react-app`.

Can anyone please tell me what I might be missing?

Comment: How do you construct your `Trade` objects?

Comment: Almost certainly you're just using that as a generic response type and expecting TypeScript to magically instantiate the class from JSON for you; it won't. (It _can't_, TypeScript **does not exist** at runtime and the metadata is erased in compilation.) The getters work just fine if you actually `new` one up.

Comment: I'm constructing them from an indexedDb query (using Dexie, specifically https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.mapToClass()). I see that at this actually works at the ORM layer so from there I should be able to figure out where it is breaking further down the chain. Thanks for your comments.